# Application crash in showing popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

```
CGRect visibleRect = CGRectIntersection(self.dayPlannerView.bounds,    [self.dayPlannerView convertRect:view.bounds fromView:view]);

EventDetailViewController *objEDVC = [kStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventDetailViewController"];
objEDVC.isForiPad = YES;
objEDVC.isForEvent = isForEvent;
objEDVC.eventID = strEventID;
objEDVC.aEventDct = dict;

if(!isForEvent)
{
    objEDVC.preferredContentSize =    CGSizeMake(320,300);
}

self.eventPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:objEDVC];
self.eventPopover.delegate = self;

[self.eventPopover presentPopoverFromRect:visibleRect inView:self.dayPlannerView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
```

There is no crash log. I know this is not enough information to find problem but I post what I have.

[image]

Don't understand what to do please help.

It works perfect in Xcode 7.2 and Xcode 7.3 but crashes in Xcode 7.01.

Comment: Can you validate that all your localizable strings are ending with semicolon and all strings are well formatted ?

Comment: Check your EventDetailController.... Or post the code of event detail controller.

Comment: Plz provide the code that invoke `length` in EventDetailViewController, there might be a infinite loop.

Comment: EventDetailController 's no method call